# Applying a coupon to a single product in woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I have one product on my site. I want to give coupons out which allow for a free one. So, if the customer puts one item in their basket - applying the coupon will make this free. If the customer puts two items in, the coupon will discount the price of one of the items but leave the other one to be paid.

When I first looked at woocommerce - I assumed that the product discount would do this if I set a 100% product discount voucher. However, in reality, this is is taking 100% off the whole basket as it appears to apply the discount to all of that product items in the basket.

What I want to do is apply the 100% product discount to ONE product - not the whole basket.

Does anybody know any way I can achieve what I want to do? Via plugin if necessary.

Comment: Hi u might be looking for this plugin i believe... i have also added the post i reffered  it http://coenjacobs.me/bundle-discounts-with-woocommerce-coupons/..http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bundle-style-coupons/

Answer (score 4):

You must change the coupon's "discount type" from "cart %" to "product %".  And then define which product the coupon applies to.

[image]

Comment: I have found the article about WooCommerce discount cart which describe how to get discount on total sales, orders, shipping cost and sales per item
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/woocommerce-discount-cart/

Comment: It appears that "product % discount" no longer exists in WooCommerce.